# Tor Browser stopped by Windows defender Controlled Folder Access

Tags: windows, connection

Tor browser is stopped starting /connecting by Windows Defender Controlled Folder access.

I have in Windows defender registrated the Tor Browser .exe file, but Windows Defender Controlled Folder access continues to stop Tor starting up.

After I turned the Control Folder OFF using the procedure below Tor Browser starts up normally.

1. Select Start  > Settings .
2. Choose Update & security  > Windows Defender.
3. Select Open Windows Defender Security Center.
4. Select Virus & threat protection, and then choose Virus & threat 
   protection settings.
5. Under Controlled folder access, turn it on or off.

What settings in Windows Defender Controlled Folder Access are needed to have Tor Browser working normally again when the Controlled Folder turned ON.

Bgrds
Peter

Comment: Just had this problem, and now it's solved. I love Edge, but once in a while I use TOR, and now my TOR browser works again. Thanks for the informative reply, William T. Harper. Tõnis

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this same problem until I allowed the following 2 applications thru Controlled Folder Access: `firefox.exe`
in the folder: `\Tor Applications\Tor Browser\Browser\` *and* `tor.exe`
in the folder: `\Tor Applications\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Tor\`

After doing this, I was able to turn "Controlled Folder Access" to ON, and start up Tor Browser successfully.